# Prevent text wrapping in data table (Excel charts)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

Is there some way to prevent text wrapping of long headers with no spaces in the data table of a chart?

I was hoping to find a "Shrink to fit" feature, like the one that can be applied to cell values, or a way to display the text vertically, i.e. with a custom angle. However, the *Alignment* tab is not available in the "Format Data Table" dialog. Other suggestions are also welcome.

The text in the first three columns in this example should not be wrapped, the others are OK.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I think you would have had a proper answer by now, were there one! But you said “suggestions” and my best is: Format, Size and increase Width: as necessary (I’ve removed the legend to get more width):

[image: Data Table for Chart]

though personally I’d settle for adding data labels (as shown) and managing without the data table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - there doesn't seem to be any real solution to this.